# difference between MPI_BCAST and MPI_SEND

Tags: mpi

I know MPI_SEND will be halted until MPI_RECV is executed in the target node. What about MPI_Bcast? Does it need to wait until all other nodes receive it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MPI_Bcast is a collective operation, so all ranks in the communicator must call it. When it returns successfully, it is guaranteed that the data transfer has completed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, MPI_BCAST doesn't need all other nodes to explicitly call "MPI_RECV", and upon the next line is executed, MPI_BCAST has been completed, right?

Comment: Indeed, MPI_Recv isn't needed, since the receivers also must call MPI_Bcast and the receiving is handled within that call.

Comment: Got it! BTW, does this mean that "MPI_BCAST" can serve as a synchronizer (all nodes have to reach the same MPI_BCAST and then kind broadcast collectively)?

Comment: @HailiangZhang: To be pedantic, no. MPI_Bcast can return when the data transfer is complete on the local rank. Please use MPI_Barrier for synchronization.